# How can I co-locate files between an sbt project and an Eclipse Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I want to be able to use a single set of source files between an sbt android-plugin project, that I'll build from the command line.  I'd like to be able share the same `AndroidManifest.xml` file as well as the `res` directory.

Is there a way I can get Eclipse to create/import the Android project from the sbt project's src/main directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the kludge I used to get it to work.

First, create a temporary Eclipse Android project in your workspace with the relevant source code, manifest, resources, etc.  I'll refer to this project as `EclipseProj`.

Next, create an sbt android-plugin project from a shell in the same directory as your Eclipse Workspace.  I'll refer to this project as `SbtProj`.

Then, move the `src` folder contents of `EclipseProj` to `SbtProj/src/main/java`, as well as the `AndroidManifest.xml` file and the `res` folder.  Optionally, make sure you can build `SbtProj`.

Next, move the `.classpath`, `.project`, and `project.properties` files to `SbtProj/src/main`.

Now you are ready to import the sbt project into Eclipse.  Delete `EclipseProj` from within Eclipse (don't delete the files on disk yet, in case you missed something.)

From Eclipse choose the import menu, "Existing Projects into Workspace", and click browse to select root directory.  Choose the path to `SbtProj/src/main`, then click the checkbox to import the project.  I'll refer to this new project again as `EclipseProj` since we removed the old temporary version from Eclipse.

Now your project is imported, but the source is missing.  Right click `EclipseProj` in Eclipse and select project properties.  Click the Java Build Path, then the source tab, and the "add folder" button.  Select the java checkbox.

Now do a clean build in Eclipse and verify that `EclipseProj` builds.  If it does, and the `SbtProj` does as well, you're done and you can delete the original `EclipseProj` temporary project's files.