# Is there a way to apply a CSS class from within a style?

Tags: css

I'm trying to be more modular in my CSS style sheets and was wondering if there is some feature like an include or apply that allows the author to apply a set of styles dynamically.

Since I am having a hard time wording the question, perhaps an example will make more sense.

Let's say, for example, I have the following CSS:

```
.red {color:#e00b0b}
#footer a {font-size:0.8em}
h2 {font-size:1.4em; font-weight:bold;}
```

In my page, let's say that I want both the **footer links** and **h2** elements to use the special red color (there may be other locations I would like to use it as well).  Ideally, I would like to do something like the following:

```
.red {color:#e00b0b}
#footer a {font-size:0.8em; apply-class:".red";}
h2 {font-size:1.4em; font-weight:bold; apply-class:".red";}
```

To me, this feels "modular" in a way because I can make modifications to the `.red` class without having to worry so much about where it is used, and other locations can use the styles in that class without worrying about, specifically, what they are.

I understand that I have the following options and have included why, in my fairly inexperienced opinion, they are less-than-perfect:

1. Add the `color` property to every element I want to be that color. *Not ideal because, if I change the color, I have to update every rule to match the new color.*
2. Add the `red` class to every element I want to be red.  *Not ideal because it means that my HTML is dictating presentation.*
3. Create an additional rule that selects every element I want to be red and apply the `color` property to that.  *Not ideal because it is harder to find all of the rules that style a specific element, making maintenance more of a challenge*

Maybe I'm just being an ass and the following options are the only options and I should stick with them.  I'm wondering, however, **if the "ideal" (well, my ideal) method exists and, if so, what is the proper syntax**?

If it doesn't exist, option 3 above seems like my best bet.  However, I would like to get confirmation.

Comment: you can accept the correct answer by clicking the right mark below the vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: There's no way to do this in pure CSS.

Longer answer: Sass solves this problem via the [@extend directive](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend).

```
.error {
  border: 1px #f00;
  background-color: #fdd;
}
.seriousError {
  @extend .error;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

This lets you keep your CSS modular in development, though it does require a precompilation step before you use it. It works very nicely though.

Comment: This is definitely the closest to what I was hoping for and, as one comment pointed out, there is a client-side option via lesscss.org which appears pretty similar (although it doesn't have the @extend notation).  I'm gonna give this a shot and see if the pre-compilation is unobtrusive enough

Comment: Also, in case this helps anyone else, you can add Sass as a [builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248567/how-can-i-configure-eclipse-to-run-an-external-builder-or-shell-command) in eclipse so that whenever you save an .scss file, for example, if will compile it to its CSS equivalent.

(Right-Click Your Project)>Properties>Builders>New>Program

In my case, I chose the scss batch file as my application, had it refresh only when resources inside of my scss directory changed, and set it to run during auto-builds (i.e. on save)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you cannot do `apply-class:".red";`

to perform this type of action i will suggest you to use this method

```
.red {color:#e00b0b;}
h2 {font-size:1.4em; font-weight:bold;}
.mymargin{margin:5px;}

<h2 class="red mymargin">This is h2</h2>
```

and to use in div

```
<div id="div1" class="red mymargin"></div>
```

In this case if you will change in `.red` class.it will be changed everywhere

Comment: While this is definitely the best answer from a pure CSS/HTML perspective, I found Chris's more directly addressed what I was hoping to accomplish... even if it does require an external tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DOM in javascript to edit the id and/or class attributes of HTML tags dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with DarthCaesar and jhonraymos. To update a class using JavaScript, all you would need is a simple:

```
function toggleColorClass(e){
    var redClass = document.getElementsByClassName('red');
    redClass.removeAttribute('class', 'red');
    /*Set the class to some other color class*/
    redClass.setAttribute('class', 'blue');
}
```

Of course, to make this work, you would need to include the above function in your document somewhere... if this is all the JS you're using you can probably stick it in the head or even use it inline. You would probably also want to write it so that the toggle goes in both directions, i.e. turning red on and off. Furthermore, jhonray's snippet is probably how you would want to mark up your CSS.