# Promote css stylings from class to element

Tags: css

I'm using a css from outside, that I can't change (company standard appearance). It defines some styles I want to use, like

```
.tableclass { blah; blah }
```

But this requires me to specify a class in my HTML tags, like

```
<table class="table class">
```

My HTML is generated by another tool, I'd rather not have to edit it. So I'd like to interpose an additional css that promotes that class-specific styling to all table elements.

The discussion [Is there a way to apply a CSS class from within a style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649703/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-css-class-from-within-a-style) (sass "@extend") comes pretty close to what I want, but it seems only to work to turn one class spec into another class spec, not to promote it as described here. That is, this works:

```
/* File1.css */
.tabletype { blah; blah }

/* File2.css */
.mytabletype { @extend .tabletype }

/* Page.html */
<table class="mytabletype">
```

but this does not:

```
/* File1.css */
.tabletype { blah; blah }

/* File2.css */
table{ @extend .tabletype }

/* Page.html */
<table>
```

Can it be done?

Comment: To be clear, did you setup SASS on your server and tried the example above to make sure it didn't work? Or are you speculating that it wouldn't work?

Comment: Check if this http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extend under Selector Sequences works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You really should just edit the HTML to include the classes so you keep your code simple.

That said, you could accomplish the same effect with jQuery pretty easily:

```
$('table').addClass('custom_table');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/justincook/QuEkk/