# Eclipse plugin for TypeScript?

Tags: eclipse, typescript

The new Microsoft [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) language (typed superset of JavaScript) seems very interesting, is there any alpha / incubator project that attempts to support it in Eclipse? Or is it too early to even wish for it

Comment: Also an IDEA plugin might be nice: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13714

Comment: JetBrains are fast... EAP TypeScript plugin for WebStorm: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP

Comment: There is an open feature request on the TypeScript issue tracker: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/491 might use some more votes

Comment: You can try TypEcs http://typecsdev.com It provides all the basic functions like code editing & navigation, code completion, refactoring. Also it has "Open Type" search dialog and "Add Type Definition", which is an additional value comparing to another plugin available. For the next release in May we also plan to have debug support

Comment: Yeah TypEcs (http://typecsdev.com/) and Eclipse TypeScript(https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript) are both *well maintained* with big player support.

Comment: Eclipse Wild Web Developer ( https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-web-development-eclipse-ide ) is currently the best plugin for TypeScript (and others) in Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check [this](https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript) open source plugin which is build by [palantir](http://www.palantir.com).

Comment: How do you use code completion in Zend Studio which is build on eclipse?

Comment: This plugin requires latest Eclipse version 4.3, you should first check if zend studio works with it. If it is work install zend and typescript plugin to a new eclipse.

Comment: https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript is better. TypEcs can't open some files with typescript.

Comment: The Palantir one worked fine for me after I figured out how to do the setup :)

Answer (score 17):

This question was asked the day TypeScript was released, so as of today (Oct 2nd 2012), there is no support. Having said that, the [XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) team -- a team responsible for rapidly creating DSLs -- is aware of TypeScript and I wouldn't be surprised if they do something.

Another place to look is Microsoft. Depending on what their motivation is with TypeScript, they may push for an Eclipse project (although I doubt it).

Comment: At his Goto Aarhus 2012 keynote, Anders Hejlsberg explicitly mentions an Eclipse plugin as something "somebody" could build using the source code they provided. So don't expect this directly from Microsoft. Assuming that they are going for maximum traction, one could, however, expect them to support such a project with know-how.

Comment: I wonder if using the Dart eclipse project as the base would be worthwhile?

Comment: @John interesting idea... I thought perhaps cloning JSDT... https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.jsdt.core

Comment: If this is the same JSDT... start over.

Comment: @EranMedan Well, thanks for squatting on the name, I guess.

Comment: I don't have any Eclipse experience, but the excellent TypeScript parser, analyser (and compiler) code provided by Microsoft makes me think any challenges in creating an Eclipse plugin would be in wrangling with the Eclipse framework itself. How hard is it to create support for a new language in Eclipse? Syntax highlighting is a start, but "feeding in" symbols from the Typescript engine to Eclipse would be the holy grail, no?

Comment: @aaaidan XText is supporting all that you said, but as far as I know it's designed more toward JVM based languages, I didn't find for example an XText JavaScript grammar to build upon. As John said using the existing JavaScript basic editor in eclipse is "not recommended". Only having syntax highlighting doesn't justify an eclipse plugin, you can use sublime text 2, emacs or vim for that, but having full static autocompletion / content assist and full refactor / quick fix support is going to be worth the effort I think.

Comment: Well, I for one welcome the task of creating (or porting, ideally) a Javascript grammar to XText, then TypeScript support. XText looks pretty capable. Does anyone here have any experience with it? I'm keen to give it a go, but my mileage my vary.

Answer (score 5):

Orion (the web based eclipse ide) would be a good fit. It is already using nodejs, so it would be easier to incorporate tsc and the language services. Right now they already support Javascript including some type inference. I understood typescript is on their radar.

Comment: Orion can use the [CodeMirror plugin](http://mamacdon.github.com/orion-codemirror/codeMirrorPlugin.html), which supports TypeScript (although it is not listed).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the beta of an Eclipse Typescript plugin was uploaded on Aug 7 2013. I haven't had a chance to try it out yet but it looks promising.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript#.UgfEuD9IG-V

https://github.com/palantir/eclipse-typescript

Answer (score 2):

Until a specific plugin is implemented, if you are adventurous enough, you might try and just use JSDT and associate *.ts files with the JavaScript editor. If you get JavaScript validation errors, disable the JavaScript Validator under Project > Properties > Builders. For automatic TypeScript compiling, you can set up an external builder as described [here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-96_non_ant_pjs.htm) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8248567/how-can-i-configure-eclipse-to-run-an-external-builder-or-shell-command).
My settings:

- Main

  - Location: /usr/local/bin/tsc
  - Working directory: ${build_project}
  - Arguments: ${build_files:f}
- Refresh

  - Refresh resources upon completion: checked
  - The folder containing the selected resource
- Environment

  - PATH = /user/local/bin
- Build Options

  - Allocate console: checked
  - Run the builder: During auto builds
  - Specify Resources: a folder that contains *.ts files

Comment: I just associated .ts and .d.ts files as JavaScript. Eeek! Horrible errors everwhere in my code because Eclipse doesn't understand the colon or type indicator of variables, function returns, etc.

Comment: @OliverMoran Strange, I don't get any Javascript validation errors... What are your versions? I have Eclipse 4.2.1 and JSDT 1.4.1. However, I updated the answer on what to do in your case.

Comment: Thanks, thSoft. Actually, I'm using Apatana - an Eclipse derivative: 3.7.2 (Indigo).

I can disabled JS validation here: Preferences > Aptana Studio > Validation > JavaScript and turn off JavaScript syntax validation